# Concatenate a string in TEXT data type mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, text, concatenation

I have a table named testing which contains a column with `MEDIMTEXT` type.

```
mysql> desc testing;
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | tinyint(4) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| data  | mediumtext | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the table content is like--

```
mysql> select * from testing;
+------+--------------------------------+
| id   | data                           |
+------+--------------------------------+
|    1 | This is the first data entered.|
+------+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In the column named `data` in id=1, I want to concatenate another string ex- *" Concat me "* to make it look like *"This is the first data entered. Concat me"*

I could do it by using

```
 UPDATE testing SET data=CONCAT(data,'Concat me') WHERE id=1;
```

but I think it would make the whole field to be read first, then concatenation, and in the end replacing the new made String to the previous one.
 In case if the text is too long, it would take a lot of time to do so.
like- if there is `15 MB` of text and `10 bytes` of text to concat, then 15 mb would be read, then 10 bytes of data concatenated and then 15 MB+ 10 bytes of data written back.
 
**I want to ask that does there exist any other method so that the string to be concatenate is just added in the end instead of replacing the complete?**
so that only 10 bytes are written in database.
May be I am wrong and mysql will manage the command to make it work efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `update` statement is perfectly fine.  If you have an index in your `data` column then yes your update might be slower, in which case you could disable the index or remove it before update and add it back after your update completes.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I do not have any index on that column. I have added one line in the question- "if there is 15 MB of text and 10 bytes of text to concat, then 15 mb would be read, then 10 bytes of data concatenated and then 15 MB+ 10 bytes of data written back.". Will this happen or just 10 bytes will be written to the database?

Comment: I believe there will be a lookup of `data` within that `concat` function.  Then the `concat` function returns with updated string which will then be set on the `data` column.  I do not think there is any such function that lets you add that 'Concat me' like how you wish.  Take a look at `replace` function (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html); it might be something similar to what you want, but since you are adding extra data in the end of the string, I wonder how we can make it work.